# how to remove "X" button from popup in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

How can I remove "X" button from Popup in angularJS? I don't need it because the cancel button that I have implemented has same functional but the "X" button couldn't reset modifies. It will be implemented as default in HTML:

```html
<div class="ngdialog-close"></div>
```

Comment: how would we know which popup you are using?

Comment: I am using ngdialog for popup

Comment: Not enough information because it is a 3rd party component (AFAIK angular has no built-in ngDialog directive). Perhaps you could add a link to  the github component you are using, or the CDN link if you are using one.

Answer (score 8):

While opening popup you need to pass one option `showClose` which will hide close button if its `false`.**(default true)**

**Code**

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: 'templateId',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
    showClose: false //<-- while opening dialog make it false
});
```

Comment: Can i set `showClose: false ` after opening the ndDillog i mean outside of Open.?

Comment: No, how can that would work.because configuration object will be passed when it is opening a popup.. May I know why you want to enable close button later?

Comment: Here is my requirement, First I will open ndWindow which has Payment form, once it submitted then I will display the success message in that Model Window. with 2 buttons  below it "Void","Print" in success page within the same model. I want user force to select any one button, I want to restrict him to close the window without any selection.

Comment: Oh its a special case.. So have it enabled initially, hide it with some CSS rules..and whenever you want remove those CSS rule..

Comment: Yes it is initially enabled, Thanks for Suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read documentation before integrating (using) any module in your project. Here is the complete list of options for ngDialog.

[Hide close button](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#showclose-boolean)